# Create an Excel Line - Column combination chart in C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I am trying to create an Excel line-column combination chart using C#.
I know how to create a line chart or a column chart but I don't know how to create a combined chart.
Could anyone please point me a direction or provide a short sample code on how to create such chart?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you already know how to create basic charts, I suggest you record a macro in Excel while you create a combination chart manually so you can see difference in syntax. For an explanation of all things Excel Charts, go to Jon Peltier's website. [Here's the combination chart section.](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ComboCharts.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to record a macro and see the syntax first.